# Правильно ли спроектировал (написал) часть системы?

Tags: java, swing, инспекция-кода

Собственно правильно ли я вообще сделал? Получается что таких форм(справочников) у меня будет штук 15.
Это рабочий кусок вырезанный из основной программы.
Интерфейс для окон:

```
public interface Parent {

    public static final JDesktopPane theDesctop = new JDesktopPane();

    void parentProcess();
}
```

Главный класс:

```
public class MainClass extends JFrame implements Parent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //создаём главную форму
        new MainClass();

        //на форме появляем дочернее окно. тут ещё проверка, не закрыто ли окно и тп
        ProductTypeFrame ptf = new ProductTypeFrame();
        theDesctop.add(ptf, 0);
        ptf.setVisible(true);
    }

    public MainClass(){
        super("Пример");

        getContentPane().add(theDesctop, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        theDesctop.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void parentProcess() {
    }
}
```

Дочернее окно(вот их, не считая основных окон, и будет штук 15):

```
public class ProductTypeFrame extends JInternalFrame implements Parent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**Панель со скроллом и таблицей*/
    private TablePanel tblPanel;

    /**Создать новый тип изделия*/
    private JButton btCreate;

    /**Удалить тип изделия*/
    private JButton btDelete;   //пользователь вообще не имеет морального права
                                //что-либо удалять отсюда, ну да оставим

    /**Тип изделия(днище/рабочая часть/...)*/
    public ProductTypeFrame() {
        super("СМ: Тип изделия",
                true,
                true,
                false,
                false);

        System.out.println("ProductTypeFrame");

        setDefaultBounds();

        createGUI();

        loadDataInGUI();

        setListeners();
    }

    /**Устанавливаем слушатели событий*/
    private void setListeners() {

        btCreate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
                //копируем название столбцов и удаляем поле ID
                tblPanel.getAllColumnName().forEach(columnNames::add);
                columnNames.remove(0);


                PanelForShowDialog modalPanel = new PanelForShowDialog();

                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                    modalPanel.createInputPanel(columnNames),
                    "Ввод значений:", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

                if(result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){

                    //тут вставляем данные в БД - получаем ID
                    //если удачно - обновляем данные в таблице программы

                    String id = "12";

                    List<String> newRow = modalPanel.getValue();
                    newRow.add(0, id);
                    tblPanel.setValueRow(newRow);
                }
            }
        });

        btDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                int index = tblPanel.getIndexSelectRow();

                if(index != -1){

                    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    String id = tblPanel.getValueAt(index, 0);

                    //удаляем из таблицы БД данные
                    //если прошло удачно - удаляем из таблицы программы

                    tblPanel.deleteRow(index);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**Заполняем таблицу данными  настраиваем её*/
    private void loadDataInGUI() {

        //оставим пока так, тут идет заполнение с хибернейта
        //нужно ещё придумать как

        //устанавливаем типы данных для адекватной сортировки
        tblPanel.setColumnsClass(Arrays.asList(Integer.class, String.class));

        //забиваем гвоздями именя столбцов, ибо как их хранить в бд - хз
        tblPanel.setColumnNames(Arrays.asList("ID", "Тип"));

        //пока оставим так
        List<List<String>> data = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

        data.add(Arrays.asList("1", "Днище"));
        data.add(Arrays.asList("2", "Рабочая часть"));
        data.add(Arrays.asList("3", "Плита перекрытия"));
        data.add(Arrays.asList("4", "Горловина"));

        tblPanel.setValues(data);

        //скрываем 0 колонку - колонку айди
        //tblPanel.setHideColunm(0);

        //забиваем гвоздями ширину колонок
        tblPanel.setColumnWidth(Arrays.asList(40, 140));
    }

    /**Создаём таблицу, управляющие элементы и располагаем на форме*/
    private void createGUI() {

        tblPanel = new TablePanel(this);

        btCreate = new JButton("Создать");
        btDelete = new JButton("Удалить");


        Container container = this.getContentPane();
        container.removeAll();
        container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        btCreate.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        btDelete.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        container.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(0));
        container.add(tblPanel.getPanel());
        container.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        container.add(btCreate);
        container.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
        container.add(btDelete);
        container.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));

        this.setContentPane(container);


        setStaticSize(btCreate, 130, 25);
        setStaticSize(btDelete, 130, 20);
    }

    /**Устанавливаем Max/Min и предпочтитеьный размер одинаковым*/
    private void setStaticSize(Component component, int width, int height){

        component.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        component.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        component.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    }

    /**Установим размеры формы и положение*/
    private void setDefaultBounds() {

        int width = 220, height = 300;

        setBounds(20, 30, width, height);
    }

    //по дабл клику по строке таблицы открываем окно для редактирования
    @Override
    public void parentProcess() {

        int index = tblPanel.getIndexSelectRow();

        if(index != -1){

            List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
            //копируем название столбцов и удаляем поле ID
            tblPanel.getAllColumnName().forEach(columnNames::add);
            columnNames.remove(0);

            List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
            //копируем значения и удаляем поле ID
            tblPanel.getValueRow(index).forEach(data::add);
            //запоминаем ID
            String id = data.get(0);
            data.remove(0);

            //создаём класс с панельками для модального окна
            PanelForShowDialog modalPanel = new PanelForShowDialog();

            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                modalPanel.createEditingPanel(columnNames, data),
                "Редактирование значений:", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

            if(result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){

                //тут обновление в таблице БД
                //если удачно - обновляем данные в таблице программы

                List<String> newRow = modalPanel.getValue();
                newRow.add(0, id);
                tblPanel.setValueRow(index, newRow);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Панель для модального окна(будет дополняться):

```
/**Панели для ввода и редактирования информации на любой вкус*/
public class PanelForShowDialog {

    /**Константа - на запад*/
    private static final int gbcWest = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    /**Константа - горизонтально*/
    private static final int gbcHor = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    /**Константа - нулевой Insets*/
    private static final Insets zIns = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    /**Главная панель, она и передаётся в модальное окно*/
    private JPanel panel;
    /**Список всех полей для ввода дабы вытащить из них инфу по порядку*/
    private List<JTextField> tfList;


    /**Консруктор для начала работы с панелью*/
    public PanelForShowDialog() {
    }

    /**Создаёт окно для ввода(обычные TextField)*/
    public JPanel createInputPanel(List<String> names){

        panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        tfList = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

        int i = 0;

        for(String name : names){

            JLabel lb = new JLabel(name + ":");

            JTextField tf = new JTextField();

            tfList.add(tf);

            setStaticSize(lb, 150, 23);
            setStaticSize(tf, 150, 23);

            panel.add(lb, new GridBagConstraints(0, i, 1, 1, 0, 0, gbcWest, gbcHor, zIns, 0, 0));
            i++;

            panel.add(tf, new GridBagConstraints(0, i, 1, 1, 1, 0, gbcWest, gbcHor, new Insets(0, 0, 2, 0), 0, 0));
            i++;
        }

        return panel;
    }

    /**Создаёт окно для редактирования информации(обычные TextField)*/
    public JPanel createEditingPanel(List<String> names, List<String> data){

        panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        tfList = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

        int i = 0;

        for(String name : names){

            JLabel lb = new JLabel(name + ":");

            JTextField tf = new JTextField(data.get(names.indexOf(name)));

            tfList.add(tf);

            setStaticSize(lb, 150, 23);
            setStaticSize(tf, 150, 23);

            panel.add(lb, new GridBagConstraints(0, i, 1, 1, 0, 0, gbcWest, gbcHor, zIns, 0, 0));
            i++;

            panel.add(tf, new GridBagConstraints(0, i, 1, 1, 1, 0, gbcWest, gbcHor, new Insets(0, 0, 2, 0), 0, 0));
            i++;
        }

        return panel;
    }

    /**Устанавливаем Max/Min и предпочтитеьный размер одинаковым*/
    private void setStaticSize(Component component, int width, int height){

        component.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        component.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        component.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    }

    /**Отдаём строку с данными*/
    public List<String> getValue(){

        List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

        tfList.forEach(tf -> data.add(tf.getText()));

        return data;
    }
}
```

Класс с панелью с прокруткой для таблицы:

```
/**Класс для создания таблицы на панели с прокруткой*/
public class TablePanel {

    /**Таблица*/
    private JTable tbl;
    /**Модель таблицы*/
    private TableModel tblModel;
    /**Панель с прокруткой*/
    private JScrollPane panel;
    /**Сортировщик таблицы*/
    private TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter;

    /**Сравнитель интов*/
    private static final Comparator<String> INTEGER_COMPARATOR =
            (o1, o2) -> Integer.valueOf(o1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2));
    /**Сравнитель дробных*/
    private static final Comparator<String> DOUBLE_COMPARATOR =
            (o1, o2) -> Double.valueOf(o1).compareTo(Double.valueOf(o2));



    /**
     * @param parent
     */
    public TablePanel(Parent parent){

        tblModel = new TableModel();

        tbl = new JTable(tblModel);

        panel = new JScrollPane(tbl);

        setDefaultSettingsTbl();

        setSorter();

        setListeners(parent);
    }

    /**Устанавливаем слушатели событий*/
    private void setListeners(Parent parent){

        /*По dbl-клику вызываем родительский метод*/
        tbl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                if(e.getClickCount() == 2){

                    Thread clickThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            parent.parentProcess();
                        }
                    });
                    clickThread.start();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**Создаём и настраиваем сортировку*/
    private void setSorter(){

        sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(tblModel){
            @Override
            public Comparator<?> getComparator(int column){

                Class<?> columnClass = tblModel.getColumnClass(column);

                if(columnClass == Integer.class){

                    return INTEGER_COMPARATOR;
                } else if(columnClass == float.class){

                    return DOUBLE_COMPARATOR;
                } else

                    return super.getComparator(column);
            }
        };

        sorter.setSortsOnUpdates(true);

        tbl.setRowSorter(sorter);
    }

    /**Настраиваем таблицу*/
    private void setDefaultSettingsTbl(){

        tbl.setGridColor(Color.BLACK);
        tbl.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        tbl.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
        tbl.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        tbl.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    }

    /**Получаем реальный индекс выделенной строки*/
    public int getIndexSelectRow(){
        try {

            return tbl.convertRowIndexToModel(tbl.getSelectedRow());

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Не выбрана строка таблицы!");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    /**Скрыть колонку*/
    public void setHideColunm(int columnIndex){

        tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex).setMinWidth(0);
        tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex).setMaxWidth(0);
        tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex).setResizable(false);
    }

    /**Установить ширину колонок(Arrays.asList(..., ...))*/
    public void setColumnWidth(List<Integer> columnWidth){

        for(int i = 0; i < columnWidth.size(); i++)
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(columnWidth.get(i));
    }

    /**Возвращает панель с прокруткой*/
    public JScrollPane getPanel(){

        return panel;
    }

    /**Устанавливает имена столбцов(Arrays.asList(..., ...))*/
    public void setColumnNames(List<String> columnNames){

        tblModel.setColumnNames(columnNames);
    }

    /**Возвращает имена столбцов*/
    public List<String> getAllColumnName() {

        return tblModel.getAllColumnName();
    }

    /**Возвращает значения строки*/
    public List<String> getValueRow(int rowIndex) {

        return tblModel.getValueRow(rowIndex);
    }

    /**Возвращает значение ячейки*/
    public String getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

        return (String) tblModel.getValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }

    /**Устанавливает значения строки*/
    public void setValueRow(int rowIndex, List<String> row) {

        tblModel.setValueRow(rowIndex, row);
    }

    /**Добавляет строку*/
    public void setValueRow(List<String> row) {

        tblModel.setValueRow(row);
    }

    /**Получаем количество строк + 1*/
    public int getDataSize(){

        return tblModel.getDataSize();
    }

    /**Устанавливает значения в ячейки*/
    public void setValues(List<List<String>> data){

        tblModel.setValues(data);
    }

    /**Устанавливает классы столбцов(String/Integer/Float)*/
    public void setColumnsClass(List<Class<?>> columnsClass) {

        tblModel.setColumnsClass(columnsClass);
    }

    /**Удаляет строку*/
    public void deleteRow(int rowIndex) {

        tblModel.deleteRow(rowIndex);
    }
}
```

И модель таблицы:

```
public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**Список названий столбцов*/
    private List<String> columnNames;
    /**Список списков значений*/
    private List<List<String>> data;
    /**Список типов столбцов*/
    private List<Class<?>> columnsClass;

    /**Создаёт модель таблицы*/
    public TableModel() {

        columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        data = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        columnsClass = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
    }

    /**Возвращает имя столбца по индексу*/
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {

        return columnNames.get(columnIndex);
    }

    /**Возвращает имена столбцов*/
    public List<String> getAllColumnName() {

        return columnNames;
    }

    /**Устанавливает имена столбцов*/
    public void setColumnNames(List<String> columnName) {

        this.columnNames.clear();

        columnName.forEach(this.columnNames::add);

        fireTableStructureChanged();
    }

    /**Возвращает класс столбца(String/Integer/Float)*/
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return columnsClass.get(columnIndex);
    }

    /**Устанавливает классы столбцов(String/Integer/Float)*/
    public void setColumnsClass(List<Class<?>> columnsClass) {

        this.columnsClass.clear();

        columnsClass.forEach(this.columnsClass::add);
    }

    /**Возвращает количество строк в таблице*/
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {

        return data.size();
    }

    /**Возвращает количество столбцов в таблице*/
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {

        return columnNames.size();
    }

    /**Возвращает значение ячейки*/
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

        return data.get(rowIndex).get(columnIndex);
    }

    /**Устанавливает значения строки*/
    public void setValueRow(int rowIndex, List<String> row) {

        List<String> newRow = new ArrayList<String>();
        row.forEach(newRow::add);

        data.set(rowIndex, newRow);

        fireTableRowsUpdated(rowIndex, rowIndex);
    }

    /**Добавляет строку*/
    public void setValueRow(List<String> row) {

        List<String> newRow = new ArrayList<String>();
        row.forEach(newRow::add);

        data.add(newRow);

        fireTableRowsInserted(this.getDataSize()-1, this.getDataSize()-1);
    }

    /**Удаляет строку*/
    public void deleteRow(int rowIndex) {

        data.remove(rowIndex);

        fireTableRowsDeleted(rowIndex, rowIndex);
    }

    /**Возвращает значения строки*/
    public List<String> getValueRow(int rowIndex) {

        return data.get(rowIndex);
    }

    /**Получаем количество строк + 1*/
    public int getDataSize(){

        return data.size();
    }

    /**Устанавливает значения в ячейки*/
    public void setValues(List<List<String>> data) {

        this.data.clear();

        for(List<String> row : data) {

            List<String> newRow = new ArrayList<String>();

            row.forEach(newRow::add);

            this.data.add(newRow);
        }

        fireTableStructureChanged();
    }
}
```

Может у кого будет время и душевные силы посмотреть)
Как сделать правильно?
Может ещё что-то не так?
**UPD 1**
Что делает код? Создаёт главное окно, на главном окне создаёт дочернее. Дочернее окно содержит таблицу, кой и описана в соответствующих классах.
Если вопрос был слишком общий, то можно сказать так: это адекватно или можно сделать по нормальному? И как?
З.Ы. Сию "портянку" никак не уменьшить. Предложение разместить на гитхаб и кинуть в сообщение ссылку было отклонено.

Comment: [тут вам подсказывают](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39403274#39403274), что в вопросе не хватает чёткой формулировки назначения кода и реализованной функциональности

Comment: @mymedia обновил. Не знаю как это можно спросить по-другому(

Comment: Всё что доделал, это создал абстрактный справочник. Больше усовершенствований сам не вижу.